# Clang's equivalent to GCC's -mwindows

Tags: windows, user-interface, gcc, clang, portable-executable

I know how to instruct GCC (using [the `-mwindows` flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/x86-Windows-Options.html#x86-Windows-Options)) to generate a PE using the `IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_GUI` instead of the `IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_CUI` [Windows subsystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx).

Does Clang offer an equivalent flag? If not, how can I change a generated executable's Windows subsystem (preferable using open source software)?

Comment: GCC just passes the appropriate flag to the linker, so see if whatever linker Clang uses on Windows has a flag for this.

Comment: @RossRidge I actually looked at [lld.llvm.org](http://lld.llvm.org/) but I did not find an equivalent flag, but I did not find an analogue flag :(

Comment: @ooxi Last time I checked, Clang does not use lld on Windows. Instead it uses link.exe when invoked as clang-cl and ld when run with MinGW(-w64).

Answer (score 5):

Try with

```
-Wl,--subsystem,windows
```

There are also *native*, *console* and *posix* available to use.